# how do I get ngModel attribute as raw string?

Tags: dart, angular2-dart

The component:

```
<test [(ngModel)]="someobject.somevar" someattr="someval"></test>
```

I would like to know the insides of ngModel but as raw string, in the above case, it would be "someobject.somevar".
But when I print the contents of     (self.nativeElement as HtmlElement).attributes, it just prints the someattr attribute.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get this information at runtime. The Angular transformer converts such bindings to Dart code (which is subsequently transpiled to JS code), therefore at runtime there won't be such an attribute.

One approach I could imagine, is to create a transformer that processes the template **before** the Angular transformer does, and secure the information in some form and make it available at runtime. 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular_ast can be used for that.

Comment: thanks for the angular_ast link. The idea was to not have the developer to write a "name" attribute, I would get the string after the last dot in the ngModel attribute. But it would required too much work just to skip one attribute.